# rails how to have a model for a .group_by assocation in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

New developer here.
I have a `customer_controller.rb` that collects all the completed orders and groups them by email address to get our 'customer' list.

customer_controller:

```
class CustomerController < ApplicationController

  def index
    orders = Spree::Order.where(completed_at: from...to)
    @customers = orders.group_by(&:email)
  end

end
```

I have view template like this:

```
<% @customers.each_pair do |email, orders| %>
<% total_orders = Spree::Order.where(state: "complete", email: email) %>
<% arr = orders  %>
<% amount = arr.inject(0) {|sum, hash| sum + hash[:payment_total]} %>
<tbody id="tbodyid">
  <tr>
    <td><%= email %></td>
    <th><%= orders.count %></td>
    <td><%= total_orders.count %></td>
    <td><%= total_orders.first.completed_at.strftime("%D") if total_orders.first.completed_at.present? %></td>
    <td>$<%= amount %></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<% end %>
```

What's the best way to handle the model for this?  Putting this kind of logic in the view is a nightmare on the server.  I'd like to have a model based on the `@customers` instance, but I don't know how to do that.

Do I scratch this direction altogether and modify the `order_decorator.rb` model to get the collection of customers?

Edit:  In response to a question below, here is a single Spree::Order record.  All orders have an email, not all orders have a user_id.

```
#<Spree::Order id: 334, number: "R826173067", item_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9ee91516b8,'0.2198E2',18(18)>, total: #<BigDecimal:7f9ee91515f0,'0.1999E2',18(18)>, state: "complete", adjustment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9ee91514b0,'-0.199E1',18(18)>, user_id: 45, completed_at: "2020-06-10 15:43:35", bill_address_id: 243, ship_address_id: 244, payment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9ee9150e20,'0.1999E2',18(18)>, shipping_method_id: nil, shipment_state: "partial", payment_state: "paid", email: "bobby@boby.com", special_instructions: nil, created_at: "2020-06-10 15:42:28", updated_at: "2020-06-10 15:43:35", currency: "USD", last_ip_address: "127.0.0.1", created_by_id: 45, shipment_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9ee91500d8,'0.0',9(18)>, additional_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9ee9150010,'0.0',9(18)>, promo_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9edd683ef8,'-0.199E1',18(18)>, channel: "spree", included_tax_total: #<BigDecimal:7f9edd683db8,'0.0',9(18)>, item_count: 2, approver_id: nil, approved_at: nil, confirmation_delivered: true, considered_risky: false, express: false, source: nil, purchased_via_subscription: false>
```

Comment: Not being familiar with Spree, can you post what a single record looks like for `orders = Spree::Order.where(state: "complete")` ? Also what does your customer model code look like?

Comment: I don't have a customer model at all right now.  All the 'logic' is handled in the view template which is terrible. I'll post a single record in the original post above.  Thanks

Comment: Can you explain `orders.count` vs `total_orders.count`? The look the same to me. Also is `amount` just a sum of 'payment_total` for that users completed orders?

Comment: Also is `total_orders.first.completed_at...` supposed to the first order by created_at? Are you sure your `total_orders` array is ordered by created_at? What exactly is that field supposed to represent?

Comment: @Beartech sorry for the confusion and see the edit in the controller above (I was editing for simplicity originally).  I collect emails from orders within a given time (from...to), and then have two columns: one of orders completed within the time frame, and one column of lifetime orders.

Answer (score 0):

Based on answers above you can make a query that will serve your needs in the controller and not need much else. If your DB is Postgres you can do something like:

```
@customers = Spree::Order.group(:email).select(:email, 'count(id) AS total_orders_count',
 'sum(payment_total) AS amount', 'array_agg(completed_at) AS completion_dates'
)

=> [#<Order:0x00007fbc8f0bd2d8 id: nil, email: 'foo@bar.com'>,
   #<Order:0x00007fbc8f0bd148 id: nil, email: 'jane@doe.com'>,
   #<Order:0x00007fbc8f0bcec8 id: nil, email: 'john@smith.com'>,
   #<Order:0x00007fbc8f0bcd88 id: nil, email: 'jack@jill.com'>...]
```

Notice these have no :id because they are "dummy" objects since each one is actually a group of orders that match that email address. But they all have the following methods:

```
total_orders => the count of completed orders for that email address
amount => sum of all payment_total for the orders belonging to that email
completion_dates => array of completed_on dates for that email's orders
```

You've done all of your selecting and calculating in the DB so it will be about as fast as possible and you can display it like:

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
<tbody id="tbodyid">
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.email %></td>   <!-- email -->
    <td><%= customer.completion_dates.count{|date| 
             date > (#some date) && (#other date)}.count %></td> <!-- orders completed between dates -->
    <td><%= customer.total_orders_count %></td> <!-- lifetime orders -->
    <td><%= customer.completion_dates.sort.last %></td>  <!-- latest completed order -->
    <td>$<%= customer.amount %></td> <!-- total payments -->
  </tr>
</tbody>
<% end %>
```

`customer.completion_dates.sort` sorts oldest to newest. If you want the most recent order use `.last`, for the oldest order use `.first`.

You can add any field you want as long as you aggregate them either with a function  like `count(zzz) AS xxx`, `sum(zzz) AS xxx`, `max(...`, `min(...`, etc. Or if you want the specific field for each order connected with that email you have to aggregate it into an array with `array_agg(:some_column) as some_name`. If you use any of the aggregate functions more than once in a query you MUST use the `AS xxxx` format or you will won't be able to access the other counts, etc.

```
@some_data = SomeClass.group(:email).select('sum(cost)', 
'count(id)')

@some_data.first.sum
#=> 23.45
@some_data.first.count
#=> 4

@some_data = SomeClass.group(:email).select('sum(cost) AS total_cost', 
'sum(tax) AS total_tax')

@some_data.first.total_cost
#=> 23.45
@some_data.first.total_tax
#=> 3.46
```

Comment: With the answer above you are handling getting the data in the controller with one query and just doing some counting in the view. That's not an anti-pattern in Rails as far as I know. If you really want to move it to a customer model you can.

Comment: That's the quesion...how would I structure a customer model?  How do I structure a group_by association model for @customers, which is a non Table object?

Comment: Do you really need a customer model? Are you planning on doing more with it?

Comment: Also `group_by` is an Enumerable method. If you want to group by :email in a query you have to use `.group()` in an aggregate function.

Comment: Customer could be a plain ruby object that is a class encapsulating the logic surrounding the queries you want to make.

Comment: @Beartech...thank you!  How would I incorporate a `.joins(:spree_line_items)` call so I could get method information from the Spree::LineItem table?

Comment: That is not so simple. I would need to know all the column names of the ':spree_line_items' table.